# Typescript interface extending and conversion

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've been trying to implement an extended interface with fields that are inserted after fetching data from the API.

My interfaces:

```
Blocks.d.ts
export interface InputsEntity {
    features: Features;
    commitment: string;
}

SingleBlock.d.ts
export interface Inputs extends InputsEntity {
    group: string;
    size: number;
    color: string;
}
```

In my react side:

```
const inputsData: Inputs[] = inputs.map((i:InputsEntity) => {
        i.size = inputs.length;
        i.color = '#F97C0C';
        return i as Inputs
    });
```

An error is coming up:
`Property 'size' does not exist on type 'InputsEntity'.`

I'm guessing I'm not mapping this properly, any help or direction will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const inputsData: Inputs[] = inputs.map((i:InputsEntity) => {
        const temp: Inputs = {
          size: inputs.length,
          color: '#F97C0C',
          ...i
        };
        return temp;
    });
```

type `InputsEntity` is not compatible with `Inputs` because it lacks of property `size`, `group` and `color`. but you can return a new `Inputs` type value.